# javafx CheckBoxTreeItem update parents programmatically

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-8

I have to retrieve some data from my database to dynamically create a `TreeView` and select some `CheckBoxTreeItem`s from this `TreeView`. This `TreeView` represents permissions to a menu structure.

My doubt is when I create the `TreeView` and select specific items from the Tree according to the user's permissions programmatically, the parents items don't have any status change (`selected` or `indeterminate`). But when I select any item directly from the interface, the parents get updated.

For example, here I have my screen when I select the items programmatically:

[image]

You can see that I have two menu items selected, but the parents aren't.

On this image, I have selected the same menu items using the screen, and the parents were updated with `indeterminate` status or `selected` if I select all children inside the submenu.

[image]

I have gone through the documentation, google and here on Stack Overflow, but only found examples to update the children.

Is there a way to update the parents programmatically or to call the event executed from the screen when an item is selected?

**EDIT:**

All items from the Tree have the `independent` property set to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with a workaround for this problem.
I had to first create all the `TreeView` structure, and change the `selected` property after using this code snippet:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       selectItems();
    }
});
```

Here is the code to verify the `TreeItem`s:

```
private void selectItems(){
    TreeItem root = tree.getRoot();
    if (root != null) {
        selectChildren(root);
    }
}

private void selectChildren(TreeItem<TesteVO> root){
    for(TreeItem<TesteVO> child: root.getChildren()){
        // HERE I CHECK IF THE USER HAS PERMISSION FOR THE MENU ITEM
        // IF SO, I CHANGE THE SELECTED PROPERTY TO TRUE
        if (child.getValue().id == 4) {
            ((CheckBoxTreeItem) child).setSelected(true);
        }

        // IF THERE ARE CHILD NODES, KEEP DIGGING RECURSIVELY
        if(!child.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            selectChildren(child);
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a simpler way, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case.  Parent items do get automatically get set to the indeterminate state when you select a child item. I'm not sure if this is something that got corrected from the time that this question was posted, probably not.

My guess is that there's a programming bug in how the node was selected or how the TableView was constructed and initialized.

Here's some code that shows what I'm doing, and it works! In my case, I'm using a CheckBoxTreeItem<File> for the TreeItem.

How the treeview was created

```
    treeView = new TreeView(root);
    treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object o, Object t1) {
            CheckBoxTreeItem<File> node = (CheckBoxTreeItem<File>)t1;
             if (node.getValue() != currentFile) {
                setFileDetail(node);
                showChildren(node);
            }
        }
    });
    treeView.setCellFactory(new CallBackWrapper());
    treeView.setShowRoot(false);
```

Below show the CallBackWrapper class.

```
private class CallBackWrapper implements Callback<TreeView<File>, TreeCell<File>> {

    Callback<TreeView<File>, TreeCell<File>> theCallback;

    private CallBackWrapper() {
        theCallback = CheckBoxTreeCell.<File>forTreeView(getSelectedProperty, converter);
    }

    @Override
    public TreeCell<File> call(TreeView<File> fileTreeView) {
        return theCallback.call(fileTreeView);
    }

    final Callback<TreeItem<File>, ObservableValue<Boolean>> getSelectedProperty = (TreeItem<File> item) -> {
            if (item instanceof CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) {
                return ((CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) item).selectedProperty();
            }
            return null;
        };
    final StringConverter<TreeItem<File>> converter = new StringConverter<TreeItem<File>>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(TreeItem<File> object) {
                File item = object.getValue();
                return fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(item);
            }

            @Override
            public TreeItem<File> fromString(String string) {
                return new TreeItem<File>(new File(string));
            }
    };
}
```

And lastly here some code that the selection was made in:

```
boolean selectNode(CheckBoxTreeItem<File> parentNode, String name) {
    Object[]  children = parentNode.getChildren().toArray();
    for (Object child : children) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<File> childItem = (CheckBoxTreeItem<File>) child;
        if (name.equals(childItem.getValue().getName())) {
            childItem.setSelected(true);
            //treeView.getSelectionModel().select(child); <-- this does not work!
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```